# How to pipe a file into a sub-process in Deno?

Tags: pipe, deno

I'm trying to pipe the contents of an SQL file into a mysql process to import a dump in Deno, like so:

```js
const mysql = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["mysql", "--defaults-file=my.cnf", "mydatabase"],
    cwd,
    stdin: "piped"
});

await mysql.stdin.write(
    Deno.readFile("data.sql")
);

await mysql.status();
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error parsing args: serde_v8 error: ExpectedArray
    await mysql.stdin.write(
                      ^
    at deno:core/core.js:86:46
    at unwrapOpResult (deno:core/core.js:106:13)
    at Object.opAsync (deno:core/core.js:115:28)
    at write (deno:runtime/js/12_io.js:107:23)
    at File.write (deno:runtime/js/40_files.js:84:14)
```

How to fix the error, so I am able to feed the contents of my file into the sub-process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Deno.readFile`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.readFile) returns `Promise<Uint8Array>`, so you'll need to `await` that before passing it to `mysql.stdin.write`.

> [`writeAll`](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std@0.101.0/io/mod.ts#writeAll) from [`std/io`](https://deno.land/std@0.101.0/io/mod.ts) will allow for writing the entire `Uint8Array` to the `stdin` of a subprocess (as mentioned in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68342928/how-to-pipe-a-file-into-a-sub-process-in-deno/68344043?noredirect=1#comment120806675_68344043)).

You will also need to close the `stdin` of the subprocess (see [this issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7727)).

Here's a full example:

`piped.ts`:

```js
import {writeAll} from 'https://deno.land/std@0.101.0/io/mod.ts';

const filePath = 'hello.txt';

// create example text file
await Deno.writeTextFile(filePath, 'hello world\n');

try {
  // create subprocess
  const subprocess = Deno.run({cmd: ['cat'], stdin: 'piped'});

  // write Uint8Array to stdin
  await writeAll(subprocess.stdin, await Deno.readFile(filePath));

  // close stdin (see https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7727)
  subprocess.stdin.close();

  await subprocess.status();
  subprocess.close();
}
finally {
  // remove example text file
  await Deno.remove(filePath);
}
```

```
$ deno run --allow-read=hello.txt --allow-run=cat --allow-write=hello.txt piped.ts
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks. [I figured out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68354462/1540350) that this will only work for small files. To pass an entire file (without streaming) I have to use `await io.writeAll(subprocess.stdin, await Deno.readFile(filePath));`.

Comment: @MartinBraun  I updated the example to use `writeAll` (for future readers).