# How to pass large amounts of data to process.stdin.write in Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno

Passing large amounts of data to stdin will fail. If you run this script under unix, you will get only a portion of the output of the website in the terminal:

```js
const cat = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["cat"],
    stdin: "piped"
});
await cat.stdin.write(new Uint8Array(
    await (
            await fetch("https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?feed=atom")
    ).arrayBuffer()
));
cat.stdin.close();
await cat.status();
```

The [sample feed](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?feed=atom) ends with `</feed>`, but the pipe will swallow in the middle:

[image: Screen Shot 2021-07-13 at 00 22 38]

Is there a way to circumvent this issue or did I spot a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No other than [Ryan Dahl himself answered me](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/11377#issuecomment-878646641):

> stdin.write is just one syscall, it returns the number of bytes written. If you use [writeAll](https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/io/util.ts#L136-L161), I think it would work.
>
> That said, ideally you'd stream large data, rather than buffer it up.
>
> ```js
> import { readerFromStreamReader } from "https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/io/streams.ts";
>
> const cat = Deno.run({
>   cmd: ["cat"],
>   stdin: "piped",
> });
> const res = await fetch("https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?feed=atom");
> let r = readerFromStreamReader(res.body.getReader());
> await Deno.copy(r, cat.stdin);
> cat.stdin.close();
> await cat.status();
> ```